# bootstrap-vue, SyntaxError Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, nuxt.js, ava

When i run test with ava, problem occurs in component that includes vue-bootstrap import inside.

```
import bDropdown from "bootstrap-vue/es/components/dropdown/dropdown"
import bDropdownItem from "bootstrap-vue/es/components/dropdown/dropdown-item"
import debounce from "../../directives/debounce"

export default {
  components: {
    "b-dropdown": bDropdown,
    "b-dropdown-item": bDropdownItem
  }...
```

**

```
C:\Users\myName\Desktop\myApp\node_modules\bootstrap-vue\es\components\dropdown\dropdown.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import idMixin from '../../mixins/id';
                                                                     ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I tried importing other stuff inside that component from node_modules, all works
I also did all proper babel config so it is not an issue what i thought at first.
It may be important so I'll add that app is made with nuxt.js

when I remove import of dropdown, tests inside this file pass. 
so i guess problem is on import.
Have anyone had similar problem? or konws how to solve it?